# InstallShield Limited Edition 2015 - Not installing required dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield

I've created a solution that has 2 exe's and 1 dll.  Now I'm trying to create an InstallShield package that will install both .exe's both should get the dll.
I created folders for each program, and put in the Primary Output for each project in the 2 folders.
When I run my install 1 folder has the exe and the dll, and my second folder only has the .exe.
Why is the dll only copied to 1 folder?  It should go into both folders.

Comment: Is it a 3-rd party DLL or it is generated when compiling one of the projects in your solution? Anyway, if the InstallShield doesn't detect a specific DLL as dependency for one of your projects, you may need to copy that DLL explicitly to the desired TargetFolder using InstallSheld scripting.

Comment: there are actually several dlls, some 3rd party, some compiled with my project.  InstallShield does detect the dlls when installing to the 1st folder.  My question is why doesn't it detect it when installing to the 2nd folder